# Hiding mutual friends when I am friends with both people

Tags: facebook, friends

I have two friends we will name them F1 and F2 on Facebook that were really close.  I had a falling out with F2 but I am still friends with them on Facebook.

So, I went to F1's mutual friend list and there are 8 people that we have as mutual friends but it doesn't show F2.  I went to F2's mutual friend list and it shows 8 friends but doesn't show F1.

Is there a way to just hide one person on the mutual friends list from someone is is friends with both?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to just hide one person on the mutual friends list. FYI: [How Facebook reveals your friends list even when it’s set to private](http://venturebeat.com/2013/11/21/facebook-friends-list/).